# How to trigger an alert box via condition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dialog

I'm new to JavaScript language and I've been working on a game for a few days now. The game is when the user clicked the light bulb, it will turn on. Each bulb affects the other bulb. My problem is, my code for checking if all bulbs are on doesn't seem to work. There should be an alert box if the game is already done.

I've tried to have some function then call it in the html body.

```js
        function win() {
            var allBulb = [document.getElementById("b1"), 
                           document.getElementById("b2"), 
                           document.getElementById("b3"),                       
                           document.getElementById("b4"), 
                           document.getElementById("b5"), 
                           document.getElementById("b6"),
                           document.getElementById("b7"), 
                           document.getElementById("b8"), 
                           document.getElementById("b9")];
            var index = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < allBulb.length; i++) {
                if (allBulb[i].src.match("turnON")) {
                    index += 1;
                }
            }
            if (index == 9) {
                alert("Congratulations!");
            }
        }
```

```html
<script>win();</script>
```

```
    //this is how I call my function in the html body
    <script>win();</script>
```

For those who are asking, this is my code for b1 to b9:

```
<div class = "main">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><img id = "b1" src = "turnOFF.png" style = "width:100px" 
                     onclick = "bulbFunc.b1()"></td>
                <td><img id = "b2" src = "turnOFF.png" style = "width:100px" 
                     onclick = "bulbFunc.b2()"></td>
                <td><img id = "b3" src = "turnOFF.png" style = "width:100px" 
                     onclick = "bulbFunc.b3()"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img id = "b4" src = "turnOFF.png" style = "width:100px" 
                     onclick = "bulbFunc.b4()"></td>
                <td><img id = "b5" src = "turnOFF.png" style = "width:100px" 
                     onclick = "bulbFunc.b5()"></td>
                <td><img id = "b6" src = "turnOFF.png" style = "width:100px" 
                     onclick = "bulbFunc.b6()"></td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img id = "b7" src = "turnOFF.png" style = "width:100px" 
                     onclick = "bulbFunc.b7()"></td>
                <td><img id = "b8" src = "turnOFF.png" style = "width:100px" 
                     onclick = "bulbFunc.b8()"></td>
                <td><img id = "b9" src = "turnOFF.png" style = "width:100px" 
                     onclick = "bulbFunc.b9()"></td>
            </tr>
</div>
```

This is my function to turn on and off the bulb. By the way, these bulbs are represented as buttons.

```
const bulbFunc = (() => {
        return {
            b1: () => {
                btnB1 = [document.getElementById("b1"), 
                         document.getElementById("b5")];
                switchLoop(btnB1);
            },
            b2: () => {
                btnB2 = [document.getElementById("b2"), 
                         document.getElementById("b4"), 
                         document.getElementById("b6")];
                switchLoop(btnB2);
            },
            b3: () => {
                btnB3 = [document.getElementById("b3"), 
                         document.getElementById("b2")];
                switchLoop(btnB3);
            },
            b4: () => {
                btnB4 = [document.getElementById("b4")];
                switchLoop(btnB4);
            },
            b5: () => {
                btnB5 = [document.getElementById("b5"), 
                         document.getElementById("b8")];
                switchLoop(btnB5);
            },
            b6: () => {
                btnB6 = [document.getElementById("b6"), 
                         document.getElementById("b7")];
                switchLoop(btnB6);
            },
            b7: () => {
                btnB7 = [document.getElementById("b7")];
                switchLoop(btnB7);   
            },
            b8: () => {
                btnB8 = [document.getElementById("b8")];
                switchLoop(btnB8);
            },
            b9: () => {
                btnB9 = [document.getElementById("b9"), 
                         document.getElementById("b4")];
                switchLoop(btnB9);
            }
        };
    })();
```

Comment: Do you call the script at the end of the <body>?

Comment: Yes I called it before </body>

Comment: can you add your html code with nodes b1-9?

Comment: And how do you change the turn on/off - by changing src? Can you share that code as well.

Comment: I've edited the post for reference. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the switchLoop function does, but are you calling the `win` function everytime a lightbulb changes state?

I think the `win` function gets called only when the page loads, because it is put in it's own script tag.
If you aren't calling the `win` function besides from the script tag, try calling it whenever a user clicks a lightbulb or a lightbulb's state changes.

Comment: Oh, the switchLoop checks if the bulb is off, then it will turn on. Otherwise, the bulb will off if it is on. I like your idea but what I want win function to do is an alert box will appear if all the bulbs are on, which informs the user that he/she completed the game :(

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, below is js and HTML for same: 
I was not able to upload images. turnON.png and turnOFF.png are being used to turn bulb on and off respectively.

Also alert box shows up as soon as you click on last bulb.

```js
  function isBulbON(img){
       return img.src.indexOf("turnON.png") > -1;
  }
          
  function toggle(sender){
   sender.src = isBulbON(sender) ? "turnOFF.png" : "turnON.png";
               if(Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("bulb")).every(isBulbON)===true){
                    alert("All bulb ON");
               }
  }
```

```html
<div class = "main">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img class="bulb" id = "b7" src = "turnOFF.png" style = "width:100px" 
                             onclick = "toggle(this)"/></td>
                        <td><img class="bulb" id = "b8" src = "turnOFF.png" style = "width:100px" 
                             onclick = "toggle(this)"/></td>
                        <td><img class="bulb" id = "b9" src = "turnOFF.png" style = "width:100px" 
                             onclick = "toggle(this)"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: I don't know how, but Snippet is working. At least functionality is visible now.